# How do I obtain the Index of a ListViewItem?

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview

I have a list view that uses a collectionsource and wish to set the background colour of the ListViewItems depending upon whether their index in the list matches a value held in the view model. To do this I am binding the background of the listVeiwItem to the value in the ViewModel, and using a converter to determine the background colour.  To make this determination the converter needs to be passed the ListViewItem's index. How do I obtain the index using XAML?

Here is the XAML for the data template used by the ListView:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ILMemberTemplate">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="{Binding Path=ListIndex, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource ParticipantBackground}, ConverterParameter={???}}">
        <TextBlock
            Width="200"
            TextAlignment="Left"
            Foreground="{Binding Path=IsPC, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource ParticipantColour}}"
            Text="{Binding Path=Name, Mode=OneWay}"/>
        <TextBlock
            Width="40"
            TextAlignment="Center"
            Foreground="{Binding Path=IsPC, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource ParticipantColour}}"
            Text="{Binding Path=Initiative, Mode=OneWay}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Any reason why you wouldn't just have an appropriate property in the item class? As a note, you don't need to explicitly set `Mode=OneWay` on the Bindings in your DataTemplate.

Comment: I considered that, but I'm doing sorting in the Collection Source, which I thik means the index isnt guarnteed to remain static. I could do the sorting in the view model, but it seems like that is duplicating functionality I can get for free using the Collection Source.

Comment: Not sure if it would be for free. While getting an item's index is easy, you still won't get any notification out of the box when it changes.

Comment: By 'for free' I was meaning the CollectionSource has sorting (through SortDescription elements) written in to in, so it seems like duplication of effort to then have to write your own sorting at ViewModel level.

Comment: Do you want the index in the source collection or the one in the sorted view?

Comment: I'm after the one in the sorted view. i.e. the 'row' ltem is displayed on the List View.

Comment: @JamesMacFarquhar why dont you bind the color from the ViewModel and update it based on your ViewModel value. doing so you don't want to mess with the index.

Answer (score 0):

You can't obtain the index in XAML and pass it as a `ConverterParameter`. This is not possible. But you can use a multi converter and bind to both the `ListIndex` and the parent `ListViewItem` container, e.g.:

```
class MultiConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var listIndex = values[0];
        //...
        ListViewItem item = value as ListViewItem;
        ListView lv = FindParent<ListView>(item);
        ICollectionView view = lv.ItemsSource as ICollectionView;
        IEnumerator e = view.GetEnumerator();
        int index = 0;
        while (e.MoveNext())
        {
            if (Equals(item.DataContext, e.Current))
                return index;
            else
                index++;
        }

        //return some brush based on the indexes..
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    private static T FindParent<T>(DependencyObject dependencyObject) where T : DependencyObject
    {
        var parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(dependencyObject);

        if (parent == null) return null;

        var parentT = parent as T;
        return parentT ?? FindParent<T>(parent);
    }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ILMemberTemplate">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <StackPanel.Background>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource multiConverter}">
                <Binding Path="ListIndex" />
                <Binding Path="." RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=ListViewItem}" />
            </MultiBinding>
        </StackPanel.Background>
        <!-- ... -->
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Thank you mm8! I was hoping it might be directly accessible by Relative Source some how... Oh well. I'll use your solution.